# Add multiple index levels to existing pandas index

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a `df` with a regular datetime index. I need to add multiple index levels. What's a pythonic way to achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-01-10")
vals = {"values": np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=vals, index=idx)
df.index.name = "time"
```

I need to add, for example, two new index levels. They must prepend the current index level "time". The result should look like this.

```
                              values
L0_name  L1_name  time              
L0 value L1 value 2020-01-01      87
                  2020-01-02      46
                  2020-01-03      19
                  2020-01-04      44
                  2020-01-05      94
                  2020-01-06      58
                  2020-01-07      74
                  2020-01-08      32
                  2020-01-09      64
                  2020-01-10      84
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), append to existing index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then change order of them by [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(L0_name = 'L0 value', L1_name='L1 value')
         .set_index(['L0_name','L1_name'], append=True)
         .reorder_levels([1,2,0]))
```

Or create new `MultiIndex`, e.g. by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and overwrite existing index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['L0 value'],['L1 value'], df.index], 
                                 names=['L0_name','L1_name','time'])

df1 = df.set_index(idx)
```

---

```
print (df1)
                              values
L0_name  L1_name  time              
L0 value L1 value 2020-01-01      84
                  2020-01-02      31
                  2020-01-03       4
                  2020-01-04      49
                  2020-01-05      77
                  2020-01-06      49
                  2020-01-07      15
                  2020-01-08      24
                  2020-01-09      49
                  2020-01-10      62
```